# it is possible to use python code to create automatically a gmail account?

Tags: python, gmail, registration

I want to develop a program that can create automatically a gmail account with the use of python.

Is it possible?

Comment: Check that the terms and conditions allow this. I guess that they don't.

Comment: You can check GMAIL's API document for that. Most likely no, as they are trying hard to distinguish human from machines during registration.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve your problem in python?

Comment: If this is for automating corporate account creation, other options are available, and probably more suitable, as products from Google.

Comment: thank you all for your responses

Comment: and it is the same for outlook, it will be not possible to create automatically account with python code ?

Comment: Not likely - AND also not  with JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a disposable email address, look for such a service with a public API (eg. [temp mail](https://temp-mail.org/)). Then use [http.client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) or [Python Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to interact with that API.

If your goal is to create spam or ghost accounts - don't. These services are aimed at quality assurance, ie. testing email services.